# BackGround Proceess Example in Nokia J2me Applicationn

Tags: java-me, nokia

I need my J2ME app to run in the background and still allow the user to use his mobile without problem.The app still needs to process some events in the background.I would also like to allow the user to stop the app if he wants to. Like Music Player any one can help me regarding this issue.
i had Tried by calling Display.setCurrent(null); But it is not working in my Nokia Sdks.

Answer (score 0):

There are no APIs offered for 3rd party application to be run in background on Nokia devices, by using the APIs provided for J2ME